# Android support v7 recycleview nullpoint

Tags: android, android-layout, widget

The recycleview first display is ok,but when scroll up from bottom this exception come out.
It's seem when recycleview reuse item cause this exception.
someone please help me to figure it out..

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$ICSViewCompatImpl.setAccessibilityDelegate(ViewCompat.java:923)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(ViewCompat.java:1343)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.addViewHolderToRecycledViewPool(RecyclerView.java:3900)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleCachedViewAt(RecyclerView.java:3843)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleViewHolderInternal(RecyclerView.java:3880)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleView(RecyclerView.java:3804)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.removeAndRecycleViewAt(RecyclerView.java:5529)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:1143)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleViewsFromEnd(LinearLayoutManager.java:1218)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleByLayoutState(LinearLayoutManager.java:1242)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1268)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1102)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:959)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:3062)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:524)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
03-13 11:13:13.810: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4819)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post your `onBindViewHolder` method?

Comment: @Gunaseelan my mistake , i put a gridview within RecycleView ,remove it will be all right

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue with my first demo project. I noticed that I was faced this issue when I used older version of **android-support-v4.jar**
After Puting  **android-support-v4.jar** latest from **../adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v4** It solved. So Please change your jar file and run your app. I hope it will help you.